# Cannot Derefrence IntPtr in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, intptr

I wrote a class that implements the IGroupPolicyObject Interface in COM.
one of the method now returns IntPtr object in C#:

```
IntPtr ghKey = objectGPolicy.GetRegistryKey(GpoSectionMachine);
```

I want to derefrence that pointer when using the RegistryKey object that belongs to Microsot.Win32 namespace.

This DOESN'T work:

```
(RegistryKey)ghKey = rootKey.CreateSubKey(policyPath);
```

I can't find how to derefrence an IntPtr. Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: huh; I even look for that method before I answered because I was sure there was one and didn't see it. THPT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`IGroupPolicyObject.GetRegistryKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't return a .NET `RegistryKey` object, it returns a Win32 registry key handle (an `HKEY`). There are two useful things you can do with an `IntPtr` value that contains a native HKEY. First, you can pass it to other Win32 [registry access functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you use it this way, you also need to manually close it by calling `RegCloseKey` when you're done, or it will leak the handle.

As @HansPassant helpfully points out in his comment, your second (and probably better) option is to turn it into a `SafeRegistryHandle` and use it to get a `RegistryKey` object:

```
var hkey = gpo.GetRegistryKey(GpoSectionMachine);
var safeHandle = new SafeRegistryHandle(hkey, true);
var reg = RegistryKey.FromHandle(safeHandle);
```

If you wrote a managed *implementation* of `IGroupPolicyObject` and it returns an actual `RegistryKey` object from this function, then:

1. You did it wrong and your implementation is not portable to any other consumer of `IGroupPolicyObject`, and
2. You must have manually marshalled your `RegistryKey` object *into* an `IntPtr` in your implementation, so just do the opposite to get it back out. (But really -- don't do that, you are breaking the COM contract by returning the wrong type.)

An implementation of this method should instead be written to return a `SafeRegistryHandle` (the marshaler will, I believe, automatically convert between `SafeHandle` and an unmanaged handle). `RegistryKey.Handle` is one of these so you can use the C# classes right up until you need to return something from your implementation.

Comment: from the GetRegistryKey Function my managed implementation returns IntPtr value. Can you give an example of how can I use that IntPtr with the registry access functions in C#? Thanks

Comment: The Win32 registry access functions all take an HKEY value, which is translated into C# as an IntPtr. Assuming that your GetRegistryKey function is returning a valid HKEY as an IntPtr you just pass that value directly back to, say RegQueryValueEx.

Comment: but the RegQueryValueEx is C++ not C#. that's the whole point I want C#.

Comment: RegQueryValueEx is Win32, not "C++", you call it from C# using P/Invoke. But see my edits: there is a way to stay in managed code by shifting between `IntPtr` and a `SafeRegistryHandle` as needed.

Comment: Thank You. I ended up using Interops with DllImport.